# Alter width of axes in chart.js v3

Tags: chart.js

I want a graph with no gridlines but with nice thick axes. I have managed to remove the gridlines using:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  y: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
},
```

The main axes still remain. I want this but I want to make them thicker and black. I can't find a way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you will find more [grid](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/samples/scale-options/grid.html) or [grid-line-configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration)

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 4,
      },
    },  
    y: {
      grid: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 4,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was the right answer